# Magento database size reduction

Tags: magento-1.7, database

I am using web shop which is working on Magento 1.7.02.

MySQL database is just hitting the limit of available size from hosting company (500mb) 
As usually I clear those tables:

```
log_customer 
log_quote 
log_summary 
log_summary_type 
log_url 
log_url_info 
log_visitor 
log_visitor_info 
log_visitor_online
```

But slowly running out of the space. Those below take most of space (about 350mb combined)

```
mg_report_viewed_product_index
mg_report_event
mg_catalogsearch_result
```

Is any of those ok to be emptied?
Any suggestions which tables can be emptied to trim database size?

Thanks in advance

Marcin

Answer (score 2):

You can reduce your database size by TRUNCATING these tables:

```
dataflow_batch_export
dataflow_batch_import
log_customer
log_quote
log_summary
log_summary_type
log_url
log_url_info
log_visitor
log_visitor_info
log_visitor_online
report_viewed_product_index
report_compared_product_index
report_event
```

For more/details check here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3638361/clearing-magento-log-data

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help. Trimmed the size from 486MB to 137MB.

Comment: Glad that helps, please mark answer as accepted so may helps to others :)